# Как я могу сделать менюшку выбора файла/каталога в C++?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

Может есть что-то в winapi? Ну или в Qt на крайний случай.
[image: Вот такую менюшку]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/common-file-dialog

Comment: Посмотрите на текущую ссылку, случайно два раза оставил на дотнет а не винапи :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinAPI:

- Выбор папки: [SHBrowseForFolder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shbrowseforfoldera) [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034943/win32-select-directory-dialog-from-c-c)
- Выбор файла: [GetOpenFileName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamea) [GetSaveFileName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getsavefilenamea)

Qt:

- Выбор папки: [QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory)
- Выбор файла: [QFileDialog::getOpenFileName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) [QFileDialog::getSaveFileName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName)

В  boost нет никакого GUI, поэтому нет и соответствующих диалогов.